# Importance of Tracelessness of Tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, trace, scale-invariance

What makes the trace-free tensor (or part of it) so important?
As in trace-free *Ricci* tensor or *Weyl* tensor.

Answer (score 2):

Symmetry. A general rank-2 tensor $T\in V\otimes V$ can be decomposed as

$$T = \tau I + S + A,$$

where $n\tau = \operatorname{Tr}(T)$ ($n$ being the dimension of $V$), $I$ is the identity, $S$ is trace-less symmetric and $A$ is skew-symmetric. These "components" obey different transformation laws under a given symmetry. For example, the scalar part $\tau I$ is obviously invariant.